# Symfony3 lock different parts of file

Tags: php, symfony

I am doing an app where users may edit different parts of xml file. The problem is that I need to ensure that the same part of the file may be edited only by one user at a time, while the whole file (with other parts) should be unlocked for editing for other users.

As a solution I see logging every user editing activity to DB and check whether a part of the file is being edited or not by reading the corresponding DB entry. If there is no entry - the part is free and a user is allowed to edit it, otherwise not. While this solution seems working, is there a more Symfony-like way to achieve this? Maybe with the help of event listeners or something like that? Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is good enough.
You need to save a status in a table something like

```
line 20-30 | locked
```

once user is finished with these lines, you set the status to unlocked again.

you might try something a bit more efficient like redis, or any other key->value store.